# Why are accepted answers providing points if the question is closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

I am wondering what happens to awarded points when a question is later closed as duplicate.

Isn't it encouraging to answer duplicate question instead of marking them as possible duplicate and waiting for the OP to agree or explain why it is not a duplicate ?

Comment: I can almost guarantee that meta stack overflow answers this question but I haven't the time or motivation to look into it, but you could!

Comment: @dpollitt, thanks, I will have a look and post the answer here. It's probably an inter SE duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Points stay. And the asker also can accept an answer *after* the closing of the question, and that still gives the answerer those accepted answer points.

Comment: do you know why it is that way ? Isn't it encouraging answering duplicate question ? I edited my question

Comment: @Olivier - Questions can be reopened if the reason for closure is sorted out. I tend to agree on the encouraging front, but that's how they set it up. :)

Comment: Or answers can provide new information, which is not mentioned in answers of previous question

Comment: If different answers complements each other, shouldn't they be merged then ? Maybe the full duplicate thread (question + comment(s) + answer(s)) should even be merged into the previous one. Or maybe a new category of question could be created, containing all the "same" questions and the different answer

Comment: @Olivier, as far as I know in SE there is no practice/possibility to merge questions

Comment: @RomeoNinov, OK, that explains a lot. I'm not "old" enough on SE to see what could be done better... and someone probably has thought of that before :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Moderators have the ability to merge questions, if it is warranted. It's not always the case, some duplicates don't always add anything particularly new and so we won't bother to do it. If we think there is value in the merge, then we will.

Comment: JoanneC: so there is no (much) practice of merge :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - There needs to be something of value to merge.

Comment: JoanneC: of course. Please do not understand my words as insult :)